# Using regex to parse kindle "My Clippings.txt" file

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to use python to parse the notes file for my kindle so that I can keep them more organized than the chronologically ordered list that the kindle automatically saves notes in. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble using regex to parse the file. Here's my code so far:

```
import re


def parse_file(in_file):
    read_file = open(in_file, 'r')
    file_lines = read_file.readlines()
    read_file.close()
    raw_note = "".join(file_lines)

    # Regex parts
    title_regex = "(.+)"
    title_author_regex = "(.+) \((.+)\)"

    loc_norange_regex = "(.+) (Location|on Page) ([0-9]+)"
    loc_range_regex = "(.+) (Location|on Page) ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)"

    date_regex = "([a-zA-Z]+), ([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)"  # Date
    time_regex = "([0-9]+):([0-9]+) (AM|PM)"  # Time

    content_regex = "(.*)"
    footer_regex = "=+"

    nl_re = "\r*\n"

    # No author
    regex_noauthor_str =\
    title_regex + nl_re +\
    "- Your " + loc_range_regex + " | Added on " +\
    date_regex + ", " + time_regex + nl_re +\
    content_regex + nl_re +\
    footer_regex

    regex_noauthor = re.compile(regex_noauthor_str)
    print regex_noauthor.findall(raw_note)

parse_file("testnotes")
```

Here is the contents of "testnotes":

```
Title
- Your Highlight Location 3360-3362 | Added on Wednesday, March 21, 2012, 12:16 AM

Note content goes here
==========
```

What I want:

```
[('Title', 'Highlight', 'Location', '3360', '3362', 'Wednesday', 'March', '21', '2012', '12', '16', 'AM',
```

But when I run the program, I get:

```
[('Title', 'Highlight', 'Location', '3360', '3362', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')]
```

I'm fairly new to regex, but I feel like this should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `" | Added on "`, you need to escape the `|`.
Replace that string with `" \| Added on "`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `|` in  `"- Your " + loc_range_regex + " | Added on " +\`

to: `"- Your " + loc_range_regex + " \| Added on " +\`

`|` is the OR operator in a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone need an update to this, the following works with Paperwhite & Voyage Kindles in 2017 : https://gist.github.com/laffan/7b945d256028d2ffaacd4d99be40ca34

Comment: any updates? Because it dosent work for me = empty array. Even with posted here 'contents of "testnotes"'.'